# How to dump only specific tables from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

If my database has 10 tables and I want to dump only 3 tables. Is it possible with `mysqldump` command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take backup of a single table in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682916/how-to-take-backup-of-a-single-table-in-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 243, accepted):

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
```

i.e.

```
mysqldump -u username -p db_name table1_name table2_name table3_name > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're in local machine then use this command

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h127.0.0.1 --port = 3306 -u [username] -p [password] --databases [db_name] --tables [tablename] > /to/path/tablename.sql;
```

For remote machine, use below one

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h [remoteip] --port = 3306 -u [username] -p [password] --databases [db_name] --tables [tablename] > /to/path/tablename.sql;
```

Comment: Great! just if you add `--where="CONDITION='VALUE'"` would be great