# How to take backup of a single table in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, backup, restore

By default, `mysqldump` takes the backup of an entire database. I need to backup a single table in MySQL. Is it possible? How do I restore it?

Comment: Compress data dump: mysqldump --defaults-group-suffix=db your_db table_name | gzip > table_name-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M).sql.gz

Answer (score 1039, accepted):

### Dump and restore a single table from .sql

**Dump**

```
mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

**Dumping from a remote database**

```
mysqldump -u <db_username> -h <db_host> -p db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

For further reference:

http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/lamp/MySQL_Export_Backup/index.html

**Restore**

```
mysql -u <user_name> -p db_name
mysql> source <full_path>/table_name.sql
```

or in one line

`mysql -u username -p db_name < /path/to/table_name.sql`

---

### Dump and restore a single table from a compressed (.sql.gz) format

Credit: [John McGrath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2200800/john-mcgrath)

**Dump**

```
mysqldump db_name table_name | gzip > table_name.sql.gz
```

**Restore**

```
gunzip < table_name.sql.gz | mysql -u username -p db_name
```

---

Comment: SQL usually compresses well--you can pipe the command above through gzip and the resulting file will be much smaller:

`mysqldump db_name table_name | gzip > table_name.sql.gz`

to restore:

`gunzip < table_name.sql.gz | mysql -u username -p db_name`

Comment: What if you want to include the password on the command line? So you are already using -pPASSWORD

Comment: mysqldump `--where='where_condition', -w 'where_condition' Dump only rows selected by the given WHERE condition.`

Answer (score 33):

[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) can take a tbl_name parameter, so that it only backups the given tables.

```
mysqldump -u -p yourdb yourtable > c:\backups\backup.sql
```

Answer (score 16):

try

```
for line in $(mysql -u... -p... -AN -e "show tables from NameDataBase");
do 
mysqldump -u... -p.... NameDataBase $line > $line.sql ; 
done
```

- $line cotent names tables ;)

Comment: This is handy for dumping a database into separate table queries - may I know what exactly the options do?

Comment: Hello, -AN(--no-auto-rehash, **-A** | --skip-column-names, **-N** Do not write column names in results.) -e(--execute=statement, **-e** statement | Execute the statement and quit. The default output format is like that produced with --batch.) fuente: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html

Answer (score 14):

We can take a mysql dump of any particular table with any given condition like below

```
mysqldump -uusername -p -hhost databasename tablename --skip-lock-tables
```

If we want to add a specific where condition on table then we can use the following command

```
mysqldump -uusername -p -hhost databasename tablename --where="date=20140501" --skip-lock-tables
```

Answer (score 13):

You can either use `mysqldump` from the command line:

`mysqldump -u username -p password dbname tablename > "path where you want to dump"`

You can also use MySQL Workbench:

Go to left > Data Export > Select Schema > Select tables and click on Export

Comment: just a small info, omit space between -p and password --> -ppassword, but its insecure

Answer (score 8):

You can use easily to dump selected tables using `MYSQLWorkbench tool` ,individually or group of tables at one dump then import it as follow: also u can add **host information** if u are running it in your local by adding **-h** IP.ADDRESS.NUMBER after-u username

```
mysql -u root -p databasename < dumpfileFOurTableInOneDump.sql
```

Comment: Unfortunately Mysql Workbench has some escaping issues which may lead to exporting invalid data which is useless...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the below code:

1. For Single Table Structure alone Backup

-

```
mysqldump -d <database name> <tablename> > <filename.sql>
```

2. For Single Table Structure with data

-

```
mysqldump <database name> <tablename> > <filename.sql>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code:

This example takes a backup of sugarcrm database and dumps the output to sugarcrm.sql

```
# mysqldump -u root -ptmppassword sugarcrm > sugarcrm.sql

# mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

The sugarcrm.sql will contain drop table, create table and insert command for all the tables in the sugarcrm database. Following is a partial output of sugarcrm.sql, showing the dump information of accounts_contacts table:

--

### -- Table structure for table `accounts_contacts`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts_contacts`;
SET @saved_cs_client = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `accounts_contacts` (
`id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`contact_id` varchar(36) default NULL,
`account_id` varchar(36) default NULL,
`date_modified` datetime default NULL,
`deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_account_contact` (`account_id`,`contact_id`),
KEY `idx_contid_del_accid` (`contact_id`,`deleted`,`account_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;

--
```

Answer (score 2):

just use  `mysqldump -u root database table`
or if using with password  `mysqldump -u root -p pass database table`

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this and wanted to extend others' answers with our fully working example:

This will backup the schema in it's own file, then each database table in its own file.

The date format means you can run this as often as your hard drive space allows.

```
DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H'`
BACKUP_DIR=backups/
DATABASE_NAME=database_name
mysqldump --column-statistics=0  --user=fake --password=secure --host=10.0.0.1  --routines --triggers --single-transaction --no-data --databases ${DATABASE_NAME} | gzip > ${BACKUP_DIR}${DATE}-${DATABASE_NAME}--schema.sql.gz
for table in $(mysql  --user=fake --password=secure --host=10.0.0.1 -AN -e "SHOW TABLES FROM ${DATABASE_NAME};");
    do
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "mysqldump --column-statistics=0  --user=fake --password=secure --host=10.0.0.1 --routines --triggers --single-transaction --databases ${DATABASE_NAME} --tables ${table} | gzip > ${BACKUP_DIR}${DATE}-${DATABASE_NAME}-${table}.sql.gz"
    mysqldump --column-statistics=0  --user=fake --password=secure --host=10.0.0.1 --routines --triggers --single-transaction --databases ${DATABASE_NAME} --tables ${table} | gzip > ${BACKUP_DIR}${DATE}-${DATABASE_NAME}-${table}.sql.gz
done
```

We run this as bash script on an hourly basis, and actually have HOUR checks and only backup some tables through the day, then all tables in the night.

to keep some space on the drives, the script also runs this to remove backups older than X days.

```
# HOW MANY DAYS SHOULD WE KEEP
DAYS_TO_KEEP=25
DAYSAGO=$(date --date="${DAYS_TO_KEEP} days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H")
echo $DAYSAGO
rm -Rf ${BACKUP_DIR}${DAYSAGO}-*
echo "rm -Rf ${BACKUP_DIR}${DAYSAGO}-*"
```