# where is my database saved when I create it in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

I'm completely new to ubuntu and MySQL and I created a new database via:

```
mysql -u root -p
create database mydb;
```

Now, in which directory is this database saved and how do I specify where it's saved when I create it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your mysql configuration file (usually /etc/mysql/my.cnf) you should have a datadir property, which is the location where mysql will save its data

Something like:

```
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
```

It then creates a subdirectory inside that for each database where it will store the database content (ex: /var/lib/mysql/mydatabase). As far as I know, you can't specify one particular database to be stored outside of datadir.

Comment: Linux mint config file location: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Answer (score 5):

Usually is here:

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

But that depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to specify where it is saved. That's the point of using mysql. It takes care of all the databasy stuff for you. It comes preconfigured to "just work".

However in the mysql prompt you can use the following commands to look into what is happening and where:

```
> status
```

And for example:

```
> show variables;
> show variables like '%dir%';
```

..and more specifically `datadir` will tell you the exact location:

```
> show variables like 'datadir';
```

Comment: thanks it worked. in case phpmyadmin ui is not working, can i download data from this folder?

Comment: @ankitsingh You can, but this is in proprietary MySQL format. The files are not much use outside of a MySQL installation. You can take a look at something like `mysqldump` instead, if you want to extract data in a more general format. See for example this question for some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682916/how-to-take-backup-of-a-single-table-in-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Normally It is here.

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

One more thing, it is possible that you don't have permission so you can not copy database and can not take backup.

Follow this step to give permission :

1. open terminal
2. go to your db directory : cd /var/lib/mysql
3. Last , sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql

Done.

Answer (score 0):

run this query

select @@datadir;

this will result somthing like this /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enable to show hidden Items (then open ProgramData).
The go to "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data"

Answer (score 0):

for me it was in

```
/opt/lampp/var/mysql/
```