# Where is my MySQL database saved?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I'm following some Android tutorials to make a Google Map app that can be used on a phone and on the web and it involves some PHP and MySQL work that I'm *very* new to.

I'm using [Bitvise SSH Client](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server?gclid=CjwKEAjw7YWrBRCThIyogcGymQsSJAAmz_ndqz5ETY4NdAMq6Wiu6RCigoDe-ccMv7Y07hemEye-mRoCU7zw_wcB) to connect to my university server and then part of the task is to create a MySQL database with a table in it that can be updated with map coordinates from a user using the web app.

I can edit and view the table and database using the Terminal Console in Bitvise but **my question is where on Earth is this database and table stored?** When I log into my personal folder on the server, there's nothing there except for the PHP files I've created. I expected to see a /mysql file or similar.

Similar questions have been answered: [look in /var/lib/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754944/where-is-my-database-saved-when-i-create-it-in-mysql) but I don't have such a folder.

Comment: Which server you use ?

Comment: MySQL can be configured to save it's actual data files in different places. To get a definitive answer, you'd have to check the MySQL server config on the actual MySQL server, and if it's a uni server you probably don't have permissions to. But other question - why do you want to do this? Generally when using DB servers you shouldn't have to care about detail like this.

Comment: Can you post the tutorial page in the comments if it is online?