# Get the code that was used to create a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a MySQL table, but I am moving that over to another server. I don't want to move the contents of the database over, so I'm just remaking the new tables, but in phpmyadmin or on the console is it possible to find the query that was used to make the db table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get query that would recreate sql table in PHPMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983344/how-to-get-query-that-would-recreate-sql-table-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: You can export the DB to .sql dump file