# Keep old user with new Ruby on Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a Ruby on Rails application with around 300 email subscribed.
For technical reasons I had to modify a good part of the database, if I save the old user email and the password_digest, can I insert in my new database the old user manteining their old password?

To store password I use the following gem:

```
gem 'bcrypt'
```

In every model I have this:

```
 has_secure_password
```

In the migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

This allows me to save the password by simply doing

```
 user = User.find x
 user.password = "password"
 user.save
```

The perfect solution for me would be saving my current email and password_digest so the user in the new database will have the same password. Is that possible?

Comment: Any movement on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have several options available to you. If you are going to be keeping the User table structure the same then you can export a sql dump of the user table and just import it back into the new database and it should work like nothing ever happened.

see this answer [How to take backup of a single table in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682916/how-to-take-backup-of-a-single-table-in-the-mysql-database)

You could also export the contents to a CSV then write a script to import the user information back into the database.

I would go with the database dump solution though, also most importantly **BACKUP YOUR ENTIRE DATABASE BEFORE HAND**.

Comment: Yes actually I did what you suggested, I only needed to delete the table structure from the .sql dump file!