# Will I lost mysql database after windows reinstallation?

Tags: mysql

I have a database in mysql.  I need uninstall windows and reinstall windows. I am afraid of what will happen my database after installation. Will I lost my database? Please , suggest me.

Comment: Take MySQL database [backup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6682916/5180017) before reinstalling Windows and restore it after installing WIndows.

Comment: How do you access your database? I mean by `phpMyAdmin` or `MySql workbench` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you checked this directory for your db? `C:\ProgramData\MySQL`

Answer (score 0):

By default `MySql` store database files in `C` drive, So of course you will lose them.

For your case you can `Export` your `Database`, format your pc then after installing windows and `MySql`, import it again.

**UPDATE**

1. Backup your DB:
   [image]
   *You can chose `Custom` to comprise it if it is a big one*

   2. After installing your new `OS`, Create a new one:

[image]

3. Import your old database to the new created one:
   [image]

Comment: Mysql are now on E dreive. I use phpmyadmin

Comment: The preferred option is to `Export` then `Import` or `Backup`, @Shyful