# My SQL--how to insert Data One database into another Database

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL databases DB1 and DB2, DB1 is on Online server, and DB2 is on local machine(localhost), Now i want to insert some data into DB2's table named db2_table from DB1's table named db1_table using MySQL QUERY. So it is possible or not?

Comment: It is possible. Do you have phpMyAdmin installed or do you have only command line interface?

Comment: yes..i have installed  phpMyAdmin

Comment: Actually this might be what you are looking for if command line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683000/2008111 and if you have phpMyAdmin just go to export, advanced, select the tables you need to export and then in other DB go to import.

Comment: I am working on a project in which the client requires an online as well as an offline application. Offline application data will be manually synced to online database linked to the web application.

Comment: If you want both databases to be kept identifcal, it sounds vaguely like you're looking for replication.  Have you looked up MySQL replication?

Comment: yes..I have 2 servers, one of which is a Master and the other which is a Slave. We tell the Master that it should keep a log of every action performed on it. We tell the slave server that it should look at this log on the Master and whenever something new happens, it should do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are on the same server you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO DB2.db2_table (col1, col2, ..., colN) SELECT col1, col2 FROM DB1.db1_table WHERE ...
```

but being on different servers you can not insert data in this way... the simplest way I can think of, is to dump data from the source db (with phpmyadmin, for instance) and import it into the target db.

Comment: are you try this query ?

Comment: I am working on a project in which the client requires an online as well as an offline application. Offline application data will be manually synced to online database linked to the web application.

Comment: @kmgkumar: ops! there were too many parentheses (answered in hurry during lunch break), edited, thanks!