# How can i export single table from database

Tags: mysql

I Need to take single "nametable" from "MYSQLDATABASE1" and take it by all privilege & relation then import it into other "MYSQLDATABASE2"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682916/how-to-take-backup-of-a-single-table-in-a-mysql-database/6683000#6683000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will dump the whole table from the specified database 'MYSQLDATABASE1'**

```
mysqldump -u username -p MYSQLDATABASE1 table_name > nametable.sql
```

**This will load the dumped table into the required database 'MYSQLDATABASE2'**

```
mysql -u username -p MYSQLDATABASE2 < nametable.sql
```

regarding the privileges & relationship i think this part will require you to manually lookup for them and do it manually table by table