# Transferring table from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0, showing wrong data on a blob column

Tags: mysql

I am transferring a single table from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.

First, I used `mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql` in my current server(MYSQL 5.7); taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682916/how-to-take-backup-of-a-single-table-in-a-mysql-database)

Then, in my VM with MySQL 8, I used `mysql -u username -p db_name < /path/to/table_name.sql`.

The columns with the 'blob' data type are not correct, the other columns are okay.
the 'blob' columns went from *"International Master (1973); Grandmaster (1975); FIDE Senior Trainer (2004).Alexander Genrikhovich Beliavsky was..."* to *"0x3C703E496E7465726E6174696F6E616C204D6173746572202831393733293B204772616E646D617374657220..."*.

Both databases have `character-set = latin1` and `collation = latin1_swedish_ci`.

How can I properly transfer the 'blob' columns from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8?

Output when running `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`:

OLD:

```
CREATE TABLE `Player` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `born` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `died` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('M','F') DEFAULT NULL,
  `bio` blob,
  `fiderating` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rawbio` blob,
  `fidenumber` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fideblitz` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `fiderapid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `rating` (`rating`),
  KEY `country` (`country`),
  KEY `nationality` (`nationality`),
  KEY `gender` (`gender`),
  KEY `fidenumber` (`fidenumber`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `longname` (`longname`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=168045 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

NEW:

```
| Player | CREATE TABLE `Player` (
  `pid` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `born` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `died` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('M','F') DEFAULT NULL,
  `bio` blob,
  `fiderating` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rawbio` blob,
  `fidenumber` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fideblitz` int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `fiderapid` int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `rating` (`rating`),
  KEY `country` (`country`),
  KEY `nationality` (`nationality`),
  KEY `gender` (`gender`),
  KEY `fidenumber` (`fidenumber`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `longname` (`longname`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=168045 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: *Both databases have* What about a table and a column? Does server and connection charsets/collations matches too?

Comment: Does `SELECT HEX(blob_column) FROM table_name` does not show the same output on both servers?

Comment: The Collations for the table is the same(latin1_swedish_ci) but I noticed the 'blob' columns do not have a collations, I am updating that now.
Using the HEX function still doesn't show the correct data.
Thanks! I'll keep you posted

Comment: It seems I am unable to add 'collation' to a 'blob' column

Comment: blob is a binary type.  text is the equivalent character type that allows collation

Comment: could you show output of `show create table table_name` for the new and old?

Comment: follow the migration tutorial of the mysql side

Comment: `select convert(blob_column using latin1) from table;` displays the correct data; a step in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Please test data copying via SELECT INTO OUTFILE - LOAD DATA INFILE (and HEX/UNHEX for BLOB column) - does the problem remains?

Comment: try using the `--hex-blob` option when you dump the data from the old db.