# How to take backup data partially from a single table in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

Found great answer how to [backup data from whole table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683000/4632019).
But for testing purpose I want to `COPY` only partial data from this table.
When using PostgreSQL I can do:

```
echo "COPY( SELECT * FROM \"${TABLE}\" ${WHERE} ) TO STDOUT      \
  WITH( FORMAT CSV, HEADER )"                                   |\
  psql -h ${DB_HOST} -p ${DB_PORT} -U ${DB_USER} ${DB_NAME}
```

How this could be done at mysql world?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61805/make-mysql-dump-from-parts-of-each-table

Comment: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/examples-of-mysqldump-partial-backups/