# Can I migrate an existing Aurora DB cluster to Aurora Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

AWS Aurora FAQ [states](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/):

[image]

I have a snapshot of an existing Aurora (Postgres) provisioned cluster. The snapshot was originally taken in `us-west-1`, but I copied it to `us-west-2` (not sure if this matters). When I attempt to restore this snapshot to an Aurora serverless setup, I only see the option to create a provisioned cluster.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aurora serveless supports only version 10.12. Maybe your regular aurora had different version?

Comment: That appears to be it - my 10.14 snapshots do not offer serverless, but 10.12 snapshots do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via snapshot -> restore, but only if your source database snapshot has specific characteristics. To see if your version is compatible, use:

```
$ aws rds describe-db-engine-versions | 
jq -r '.DBEngineVersions[] | 
select(.SupportedEngineModes[]?=="serverless") | 
"\(.Engine): \(.EngineVersion)"'
```

yields

```
aurora-mysql: 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1
aurora-postgresql: 10.14
aurora: 5.6.10a
```

The versions that are compatible to swap back and forth (using snapshots between serverless and provisioned) change over time. If you are using a source database snapshot that is not directly compatible, you can [try](https://medium.com/@souri29/how-to-migrate-from-amazon-rds-aurora-or-mysql-to-amazon-aurora-serverless-55f9a4a74078) [mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217299/how-to-export-database-from-amazon-rds-mysql-instance-to-local-instance).