# Auto backup MySQL Database using batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am trying to make some normal /restorable backup of MySQL database. My problem is, that I only need to back up a single table, which was last created, or edited.

Is it possible to set `mysqldump` to do that?

MySQL can find the last inserted table, but how can I include it in `mysqldump` command? I need to do that without locking the table, and the database has partitioning enabled.

Comment: Did you look here: [Stack answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987366/how-to-dump-only-specific-tables-from-mysql) or here [another answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables)?

Comment: @verjas yes, i have read them. But what i want to do is, i want to dump all the tables in the database and save them in separate sql file.

Comment: So what do you want to do? Back up a single table from a database, or back up all tables from a database? If you are already able to automatically identify the tables to back up, what question do you still have, taking into consideration the links given in the comment from verjas?